# How to retrieve a list with a 1:N relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an 'articles' table, and I have a 'tags' table. There is an N:N relation between the two, so I have an 'articles_tags_relations' table too. I would like to retrieve a list of articles with tags, however in addition to the name of the tag, I need its id too. So the returned data should be something like (of course not in JSON format):

```
[[1,"FirstArticle",{"1":"FirstTag","2":"SecondTag"}],[2,"SecondArticle",{"3":"ThirdTag"}]]
```

So far I have something like:

```
SELECT article.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags FROM articles AS article LEFT JOIN articles_tags_relations AS relation ON article.id = relation.article_id LEFT JOIN tags AS tag ON relation.tag_id = tag.id LIMIT 0,10;
```

But it only has the tag names without the ids. There will be a lot of read queries on the table, so performance is important. I'm not sure using GROUP_CONCAT is the way to go, I'm open to any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Add `CONCAT` to get the id and record together, or create a separate `GROUP_CONCAT` clause for each.

```
SELECT article.*, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(tag.id,':',tag.name)) AS tags 
FROM articles AS article 
LEFT JOIN articles_tags_relations AS relation ON article.id = relation.article_id 
LEFT JOIN tags AS tag ON relation.tag_id = tag.id
GROUP BY article.id 
LIMIT 0,10
```

AFAIK there is nothing particular about `GROUP_CONCAT` that will cause performance loss.

---

Just for fun here is a query which will return a JSON

```
SELECT CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('[',row_data,']')),']') as JSON
FROM
(
  SELECT CONCAT(a.id,',"',a.title,'",{',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("'",tag.id,'":"',tag.name,'"')),'}') as row_data
  FROM articles AS a 
  LEFT JOIN articles_tags_relations AS relation ON a.id = relation.article_id 
  LEFT JOIN tags AS tag ON relation.tag_id = tag.id
  GROUP BY a.id 
  LIMIT 0,10 
) t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to do this in one query?  I'd do one query to get the articles and then a second one to get the tags for those article ids.  I'm not sure how the performance compares though.  (And it probably depends on your network speed as to the cost of the second query vs the left join.)

That said, trying to concat multiple pieces of data in a sql query feels like it is going against the spirit of a relational database and is less likely to perform as well as something the database is really good at.

Comment: No, not important to do it in one query. So you say I should do something like the following?

SELECT article.* FROM articles; SELECT tag.* FROM articles_tags_relations AS relation LEFT JOIN tags AS tag ON relation.tag_id = tag.id WHERE relation.article_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,...);

Comment: Normally, I'd do what Marcel proposed (except with an outer join).   In your case, I understand not doing that since you don't want to send back the article text multiple times due to performance/bandwidth.  So yes, I would the two queries you describe.  Almost.  You still need the article_id in the second query so you know which tag goes with which article.  The goal being to get the article text out of the joined query.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `GROUP_CONCAT()` works together with an `GROUB BY` clause. However, here are two alternatives of receiving tag.id with your data:

```
SELECT article.*, tag.id AS tags_id, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags FROM articles AS article LEFT JOIN articles_tags_relations AS relation ON article.id = relation.article_id LEFT JOIN tags AS tag ON relation.tag_id = tag.id LIMIT 0,10;
```

And 2:

```
SELECT article.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.id SEPARATOR ', ') AS tag_ids FROM articles AS article LEFT JOIN articles_tags_relations AS relation ON article.id = relation.article_id LEFT JOIN tags AS tag ON relation.tag_id = tag.id LIMIT 0,10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I seem to fail to understand your problem. To me the solutions is easy: `select a.id, a.name, t.id, t.name from articles a, tags t, articles_tags_relations atr where a.id = atr.article_id and t.id = atr.tag_id`

Of course, this doesn't format the result as you want it but formatting is not something SQL is meant for. First you retrieve the result (see above) then you use the programming language of your choice to format the result set.

Comment: An article can have more than one tags. In you SQL query, only one tag is retrieved.

Comment: No, certainly not. The result set would look like "1 article1 1 tag1/1 article1 2 tag2/1 article1 3 tag3" and so on. I mentioned that it wouldn't be nicely formatted, though.